# How to switch back between two windows in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I Create qml file like this :

```
main.qml

Item {
     width: 200; height: 200

     Loader { id: pageLoader }

     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         onClicked: pageLoader.source = "Page1.qml"
     }
 }
```

I want to back to main page from `Page1.qml`.

How I can do this Work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just set the source of `pageLoader` in Page1 to nothing:

Main Page :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Main Page"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            ld.source="Test.qml"
        }
    }
    Loader{
        id:ld;
        anchors.fill: parent;
    }
}
```

Test.qml

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 62
    color: "navy";
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Page 1"
    }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: ld.source="";
    }
}
```

Comment: @saeed Is there any way to do the same thing by using Key_onEscapePressed after the second page has loaded. I tried to do that but didn't work. I need that when the second page is loaded, if we press Escape, it will restore the main page.. Thanks!!

Comment: And to get back/return to work with escape, like @Jino is asking, you need to set the `focus: true` both in the loader and on the loaded qml page, and then you can add: `Keys.onEscapePressed: {
        console.log("escape");
        ld.source=""
    }` in the sub page to return.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you have to instanciate the loader once again in Test.qml to access it via var